# how to play a double mordent on the piano

Tags: piano, notation, technique, mordent

I am guessing the wavy line from one chord up to another chord is called "double mordent," from my looking online.  How it is played?

Comment: I have added an answer based on Double Mordent - it is a wavy line, but it doesn't have anything to do with chords.

Comment: Are you talking about a [Glissando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando)?

Answer (score 8):

[From Merriam Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20mordent)

Definition of DOUBLE MORDENT

> a melodic ornamentation consisting of four grace notes or tones preceding a principal note or tone and executed by a rapid alternation of a principal tone with its lower auxiliary tone

The important point appears to be the playing of the grace notes as fast as possible

From http://beabetterproducer.com/:

> In the case of both mordent and double-mordent the tones are sounded as quickly as possible, the time taken by the embellishment being subtracted from the value of the principal note as printed.

[image] -